# Angular Material: how to set floatPlaceholder to never

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

Library: Angular Material ([material2](https://github.com/angular/material2))

I would like to use the MdInputContainer's floatPlaceholder directive, so that the placeholder/hint never floats.

I don't see where it states the values it expects in the documentation:

> **@Input() floatPlaceholder:** Whether the placeholder should always float, never float or float as the user types.

*taken from: https://material.angular.io/components/input/api*

```html
<md-input-container [floatPlaceholder]="false">
  <input type="text" mdInput placeholder="Search...">
</md-input-container>
```

I've tried `false` and `"never"` for the values as my best guesses, but neither prevents the placeholder from floating above the input.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the floatPlaceholder input to: auto, always, never.

```
<md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
          <input type="text"
                 mdInput
                 placeholder="Search...">
</md-input-container>
```

---

**Update (Angular Material 6):**

Now you have to use `floatLabel`:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput placeholder="Search...">
</mat-form-field>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjr8jd)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set this as a global setting in your `AppModule` like this:

**Import the `MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` into your AppModule**

```js
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material';
```

**Pass it into the providers array of the module (additional code omitted with `...`):**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { float: 'never' } },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I think you mean:

import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
...
{ provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { floatLabel: 'never' }, },

Answer (score 1):

For **Angular 10** this works fine

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';


  @NgModule({
    exports: [
      MatAutocompleteModule,
      // other modules needed
    ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { floatLabel: 'never' } },
  ],
  declarations: [],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```